# Does Sombra's 'Opportunist' passive have a range?

Tags: overwatch

[image: Sombra's abilities]

Sombra's passive, Opportunist, allows her to view critically inured enemies through walls.  When I was given a chance to play at Blizzcon, I didn't even notice she had this passive until I saw the skill list she has.

How far exactly will Opportunist allow her to see through walls? Is this a global map-wide ability that allows her to view critically-injured enemies from anywhere on the map, or does she need to be at least in somewhat close proximity?

Comment: ... Oh my God that's frightening (and explains how she could see the 76 in the gameplay trailer)

Comment: I disagree with the close votes. Despite not "being released" yet, she is in a playable state at Blizzcon.

Comment: @jojo is it really a 6s disable with her ult ? How does it feel ? I've got the impression that'll be a bit retarded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the streams, its map-wide and you can see any critically hit hero through walls, no matter how far away they are.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be map wide.

Just to add to NBO's answer :
Honnestly, it's probably her only real gameplay that she will have waiting for her ult. Don't forget that :

- She's a tracer without 3 blinks.
- Her stealth has a delay where she can get knocked out of it.